# Getting Exception when setting django with mysql-server

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7, ubuntu

First of all I installed django on my Ubuntu machine

```
sudo apt-get install python-django
```

After that i created my first project using following command and a directory named 'mysite' was created.

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

Here, running the following command starts a server and i checked in the browser, minimal server that comes with django was perfectly.

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Then, I installed mysql-server running this command

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

After this i create database in mysql named 'django_first' .
And used the following command to install python module mysqldb successfully.

```
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

As of now no issue occurred. But as soon as I run this command in the directory after setting all the necessary fields in settings.py file

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'django_first',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
}
```

Now run this command
     python manage.py runserver

I get the following errors :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line  399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in execute
    translation.activate('en-us')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 130, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 188, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py",     line 177, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)    
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 159, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in     import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.sites import AdminSite, site
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 4,     in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.forms import AdminAuthenticationForm
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/forms.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 48, in <module>
    class Permission(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 96, in     __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 264, in     add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 124, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in     __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 198, in     __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])  
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 113, in     load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in     import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line     17, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module     named MySQLdb`
```

Looks to be some issue with mysqldb module not installed, but that's not exactly it is as I rerun the installation command for this.

Any ideas about this ?

Comment: try `import MySQLdb` in python console (not a django shell), what happens?

Comment: "ImportError: No module named MySQLdb"   is what I am getting when I do `import MySQLdb`

Comment: oh wait never mind I see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MySQLdb` is just the module that connects to MySQL, but it's part of a larger package called `MySQL-Python`. Just do:

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

And it should take care of everything (you probably need to `sudo` that command). In fact, I'd probably suggest you do:

```
pip install MySQL-python --upgrade
```

To assure it installs the latest version. If that doesn't change anything, follow [these instructions](http://edwards.sdsu.edu/labsite/index.php/lab-blog/404-installing-mysqldb-module-for-python-2-7-for-ubuntu-12-04) to make sure you get the latest version and all required dependencies

p.s. in general, always prefer `pip` over `apt-get` for installing python packages, since it gets updated a lot more frequently. For example, the `django` version you have installed using the `apt-get` method might very well be a very old release. To fix that, delete the django folder in your site-packages and do:

```
pip install django==1.6.2 #this is the latest version
```

Comment: As you said it was the problem with Mysqldb , but it didn't go with just upgrading MySQL-python . I was still facing the import errors. So i just built the MySQL source on my system and got it done

Comment: Sounds painful, but glad to hear it got sorted out

Answer (score 1):

After trying all the suggestions given above, I managed to pinpoint the problem of no link to MySQLdb module.

I decided to build the code and installed the source from here.
    http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/

Before building it you need to ensure the below prerequisites:

> 1. gcc compiler
> 2. MySQL Server. I used the MySQL Community Server Version

Run these commands as well:

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools python-dev libmysqlclient15-dev
```

If you are getting error with mysql_config, do not forget to fix `PATH` env. variable

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

Now we can compile the code:-

```
sudo python setup.py build
sudo python setup.py install
```

Now open your python command line and import the new MySQLdb module

```
$> python
>>> import MySQLdb
```

You should not see any import error.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `libmysqlclient-dev` is installed or not? 
If it is not installed try to install

> > sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev

Hope this will fix your issue